# Etherscan/Telegram API bot (telegram)

Tags: node.js, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, ethereum

I'm interested in building a bot for telegram that will update a user on etherscan API info.

So when a user messages the bot with a string and it will return in the chat some simple data. How do I utilize the API? I have read many tutorials but I don't really understand how the API works. I want to use node js

Thank you for any responses at all to this broad question

Comment: check out this link, it has a well-written api documentation:  https://github.com/yagop/node-telegram-bot-api

Comment: What do want to do ? Can you describe?

Comment: Yes! For example, you text the telegram bot an address or name of some token and it will text you back the value or something. Etherscan.io is the source of all this data but I want to make it accessible via chat bot.